# How do I fix slow wifi but fast ethernet with many different wifi around?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am currently using a Dlink wireless router from 7 years ago.  The wifi on it has been working fine up till a few months ago.  I have very good speed with the ethernet from the router but wireless is hit and miss.  Regular web pages can take a long time to load or not at all.

I can fix the wireless router by resetting or unplugging/plugging my wireless router but then it will get slow again in the next few minutes to hours.  I live in an apartment where there are many wireless routers around me.  A wireless channel scanner shows at least 4 different wireless routers on each of channel 3, 6 and 9.  The maximum channel number for electronics in North America is 11, so I cannot go beyond that.

My wireless device works fast on wifi outside my place. I am currently on channel 6 but the speed is still slow on other channels.  How do you get good wifi when there are many different wireless routers around on all the channels?

Comment: Could it be the location of your Wireless router? Sometimes there is other interference around the frequency that could possibly degrading your wireless router.could also be a router close in proximity to your that could be causing issues as well. I would try moving it.

Comment: You could also try borrowing someone else's router or buy a new one that supports newer technologies such as wireless N and AC. It may be that your router has become faulty.

Comment: "The maximum channel number for electronics in North America is 11, so I cannot go beyond that." actually you can.  Just load open source firmware that supports your router.  You can also accept that its time to upgrade your router, your likely to increase not only the range but the stability of the entire network by doing so to a router that supports 801.11ac

Comment: @Ramhound Just because you "can" doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Is a valid channel except in the NA.  The different between channel 11 and 13 is insignificant and WILL NOT solve the author's problem anyways.  Does not change the fact IT IS possible and saying "cannot" is an incorrect statement.

Comment: A 5 gHz network on a dual band router will likely give you a big speed boost.

Answer (score -1):

You might try to:

1. Install the newest firmware (if there is one).
2. Reset everything to factory defaults and reconfigure manually (don't import a saved file of your previous settings).

I've had luck (sometimes) with one of these approaches with "unstable" routers.

Last resort: Get a new router.